# Linking to a Self Asked/Answered Question to your own site?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In February, I wrote a question and answer about [SOQL vs SOSL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9028/soql-vs-sosl-which-one-to-use-and-when). I recently decided to relaunch my blog and make it Salesforce specific. Since I wrote both the question and answer for that post, I decided to create a [blog post](http://jessealtman.com/2013/08/soql-vs-sosl/) with the same information as that question.

I'd like to add a link to the blog post at the bottom of the question (similarly to how I linked the blog post back to the question), but I am afraid that would be viewed too much as self promotion (which is exactly what it is at the end of the day to be honest) by the community. Anyway, would it be out of line to add a link to the blog post at the end of the answer? I am just looking for some opinions.

Answer (score 11):

I am not against self promotion, and many times, answers written here are either self knowledge or self investigation and than finding the answer elsewhere.

I am not against it, while it's kept in good taste.

Also, you may want to add any information you want with your profile (as I know you already have, but this is for others that will read :-)) )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Saariko. I want to promote the community here, it has truly helped me hone my Salesforce skills. I just wanted to make sure it wouldn't be viewed negatively since I knew it would bump the question just to add my own link.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who benefited a lot from this site I can safely assume that this wont be construed as self promotion especially when that link helps us find answers to our problems.